# PHP Use of existing global search against uploaded files

Tags: php, file, search

I have included an upload script, which currently ONLY checks the upload folder to make sure that the file isn't there, which works just fine. However, I would like to somehow silently include a search function to see if it is already in one of the other directories.

The process: User uploads a prl, it checks upload folder if its there. This works. I need it to check another directory (recursively) to see if it is in any subdirectory already, and then list them out.

Just a note: $carrier is an existing subdirectory. I would like it to check the parent directory and all of its subs for the filename minus the extension, and if it exists, Error: this file already exists for "this" carrier.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("prl");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
if (file_exists("./prls/" . $carrier . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    echo "<h2><u>Error:</u></h2>";
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " is already listed in the " . $carrier . " directory. ";
echo "<hr><br />If you feel this PRL is listed incorrectly, please let us know.";
die;
}
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "-" .$carrier)) {
echo "<h2><u>Error:</u></h2>";
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " for <b>" . $carrier . "</b> has already beeb submitted for approval. ";
die;
}
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "-" . $carrier);
echo "<h2><u>Submitted for approval:</u></h2>";
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " for " . $carrier . ". <b>Thank you</b>.";
}
else
{
 echo "Invalid file. Please choose a PRL with a \".prl\" extension.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Check out PHP's DirectoryIterator class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php
You can create a function that takes a directory to search, then for each item it finds, if the item is a directory then make a recursive call to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). Here's a function that will behave like `file_exists()`:

```
function file_exists_recursive($dir, $filename) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

    foreach($iterator as $path) {
        if (!$path->isDir()) {
            if(file_exists($filename.$path->__toString()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call this function in your file:

```
if (file_exists_recursive("upload/", $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "-" .$carrier)) {
    echo "<h2><u>Error:</u></h2>";
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " for <b>" . $carrier . "</b> has already beeb submitted for approval. ";
    die;
}
```